# LSTM: inverting by entering output value to get to input value

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

How about this thought experiment. You have an LSTM network to encode a sequence of integers (inputs are `x_t`). For each cell, the weights, biases and outputs of the gates, as well as the previous states (`C_t-1`, `h_t-1`) are calculated and stored for the forward pass. Each cell has, thus, a certain hard-coded pattern. We'll use this image for a visualization aid (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory)).

[image]

I now want to take a cell with all its calculated values, and switch the input with the output. The new input is a new value that gets entered into `h_t`, let's call it `h'_t`. The computation is inverted to arrive at a new value for `x_t` that we'll call `x'_t`. Does the cell keep its properties so that there is a (non-linear) relationship between the output of a cell and the input, regardless of what the output value I enter into it is? This calculation would then be performed for the whole sequence of LSTM cells, but each cell would get a different `h'_t` value as an input.

Furthermore, would it be enough to only calculate it backwards for the output gate, since one can arrive at `x'_t` either through the output gate, the input gate, or the forget gate?